# How to populate datagridview with data which has data and images stored in sqlserver table

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, populate

I've gone through many articles about this issue. But didn't get a proper answer or may be I'm not able to understand.

I've a table which stores receipt number, batch numbers and a copy of receipt as image in database

for ex: Referenceid : int
batchnumber : int
receiptcompressed : image

I'm trying display this data in datagridview

```
 Dim sqlString As String
 Dim storeID As String
 Dim saleDate As String
 Dim ds As DataSet

 With DataGridView1
     storeID = .CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value
     saleDate = .CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value
 End With

 sqlString = "select batchnumber, [time],ReceiptCompressed from Journal where TransactionType=16 and StoreId ='" & storeID & "'" & _
                 "  and [Time] between '" & saleDate & " 00:00:00' and '" & saleDate & " 23:59:59'"




 ds = getDataset(connectionString, sqlString)

 DataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
```

Problem is an error is coming while loading the data.

"The following error occured in the datagridview

system.argumentexception.image.fromstream(system system, boolean useembeddedcolormanagement, boolean validateimagedata " etc.....

Can anyone tell me what is the simplest way to do this? As mentioned data stored in table I want to load into datagridview along with image.

Thanks
Venkat

Comment: Is the image one of [these](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat(v=vs.100).aspx) formats?

Answer (score 0):

Try to save your images as a base64 string:

```
Dim byt As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strTextOrFile)
strModified = Convert.ToBase64String(byt)
```

...and save them to your db. In order to transform the base64 strings to images, use:

```
Dim b As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(strModified)
strTextOrFile = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b)
```

Another way to work with images is to not save them into your database, but only his path.

Comment: I've an application which stores the pos receipt in database. It's cumbersome activity to compare X report (Day End) and actual sales reported. What I'm trying to do is create an application where on selection of date and store name display the X report from database and display in picture box. This saves a lot of time to the user.

Comment: What I don't understand is why the "parameter not valid" error is getting generated. Datatype of the field in sql server database is 'image' and followed the same examples in web.

Comment: Maybe is something related to the base language you are using (and your actual encoding). Could you post some values being used when error appears?